# Diferença de usar módulo e bibliotecas próprias, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou iniciando em nodejs, é tudo "novo" e eu me deparei com esse conflito.

Existem os módulos *(eu chamo de módulos, não sei se é certo)* prontos etc.. entretanto eu tenho bibliotecas como o CryptoJS que tem módulos pra NodeJS e tem sua biblioteca em JavaScript para web..

Qual é mais vantajoso de usar? O módulo ou apenas enfiar o arquivo dentro do projeto e usar, editar, aperfeiçoar etc..

e afinal, qual a diferença?

Answer (score 0):

[Modulo's](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) são bibliotecas para o node.js. Veja o trecho abaixo da api node.js:

> Node tem um sistema de carregamento de módulos simples. No node,
>   arquivos e módulos estão em uma correspondência um-para-um.

Exemplo de módulos:

- Circle.js
- Rectangle.js
- Square.js

Um package é um ou mais módulos (bibliotecas) agrupadas (ou acondicionados) junto. Estes são comumente usados por outros packages ou em um projeto próprio. Node.js usa um [gerenciador de pacotes](https://npmjs.org/), onde você pode encontrar e instalar milhares de packages.

Exemplo de package:

```
Shapes             <- Nome do projeto/package
  - Circle.js      <- 
  - Rectangle.js   <- Modulos que pertencem ao package Shapes
  - Square.js      <-
```

Essencialmente, você pode instalar o package, `Shapes`, e ter acesso aos módulos `Circle.js`, `Rectangle.js`, `Square.js`.

Comment: Fiquei confuso, o que packages tem a ver com a pergunta? Eles seriam as bibliotecas? An?

Comment: Basicamente sim, packages são conjuntos de módulos no node.js. Como por exemplo, express. É um package que contém vários módulos js.